# Create output query from two queries

Tags: sql

Have not seen straight forward answer to this so I think it is the right place to ask.
First of all the question is: I have two tables (Illustration below) and I want to see output like this (also below), heard of things like union and join, but however I am not very experienced in SQL. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9vtS.png)

[image]

Comment: This question shows neither the two tables nor the desired output.  Also, since you are inexperienced, I suggest learning some fundamentals before trying to do stuff.  To that end, I've heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes.

Comment: And by the "question shows neither the two tables nor the desired output" you mean ?

Comment: @undefined he meant that you didn't post the image for your tables or the wanted results on the question at first, just the link. But that was fixed by bluefeet on the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able get the result by joining `tableA` to `tableB` using the `id` column:

```
select a.name,
  b.text,
  a.id
from tablea a
inner join tableb b
  on a.id = b.id;
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cfadf/1).

An [INNER JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Inner_join) will return the matching rows that exist in both tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
select name, text, a.id
from tableA a, tableB b
where a.ID = b.id
order by text
```

Comment: Even though you were first the lack of ANSI 92 join syntax puts me off upvoting.

Comment: That's ok ;) I haven't been much of a fan of the `inner join` part of the ANSI 92 syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name, Text, TableA.Id
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.ID = TableB.Id
ORDER BY Text
```